# LSF “order” resource string

Tags: linux, lsf

I was trying to submit jobs to the least utilized machines in LSF using

```
bsub -R "order[ut]"
```

It works as expected but all jobs(submitted back to back) ends up in the same host(the least utilized one) and thus loads the machine heavily, eventually resulting in poor job performance. Is there a way to spread the jobs submitted consecutively across least utilized machines ? Or a way to figure out how many slots are used on a machine ?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say for sure based on your description, but my guess is that what you're seeing is an effect caused by the nature of LSF's scheduling cycle.  Here's an excerpt from the LSF documentation on the order string:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSETD4_9.1.3/lsf_admin/order_string.dita

> Suppose host h1 exists in a cluster and has 110 units of a consumable
>   resource 'res' while host h2 has 20 of this resource ('res' can be the
>   new batch built-in resource slots, for example). Assume that these two
>   jobs are pending and being considered by scheduler in same scheduling
>   cycle, and job1 will be scheduled first:
>
> Job1: bsub -R “maxmem>1000” -R “order[res] rusage[res=100]” -q q1
>   sleep 10000
>
> Job2: bsub -R “mem<1000” -R “order[res] rusage[res=10]” -q q2 sleep
>   10000
>
> Early in the scheduling cycle, a candidate host list is built by
>   taking either all hosts in the cluster or the hosts listed in any
>   asked host list (-m) and ordering them by the order section of the
>   resource requirement string. Assume the ordered candidate host lists
>   for the jobs look like this after the ordering:
>
> Job1:{h1, h7, h4, h10}
>
> Job2:{h1, h2}
>
> This means h1 ends up being the highest 'res' host the candidate host
>   lists of both jobs. In later scheduling only, one by one each job will
>   be allocated hosts to run on and resources from these hosts.
>
> Suppose Job1 is scheduled to land on host h1, and thus will be
>   allocated 100 'res'. Then when Job2 is considered, it too might be
>   scheduled to land on host h1 because its candidate host list still
>   looks the same. That is, it does not take into account the 100 'res'
>   allocated to Job1 within this same scheduling cycle.

In short, you're submitting a bunch of jobs at once and asking that the candidate hosts be ordered by the resource 'ut', but within a single scheduling cycle the hosts aren't reordered as jobs are scheduled to them.  If you spaced out your job submissions such that they were each scheduled in separate cycles, you'd see that the jobs get dispatched to different hosts.

Now, that page of the documentation also goes on to describe how to force LSF to reorder the hosts within the cycle for each job, this is done by simply adding a '!' in the order string:

```
bsub -R "order[!ut]"
```

I'd warn you though that if you have a lot of jobs in your cluster, this can potentially significantly slow down scheduling.

Furthermore, I'm not 100% sure if this will work for the resource 'ut' (because it's value wouldn't change as jobs are scheduled), you might want to try the built-in resource 'slots' which was added in a recent version I believe:

```
bsub -R "order[!slots]"
```

**Edit**

A couple of my colleagues came up with another way to get around this behavior without using the the '!' notation in the `order` string, and that is to set the `JOB_ACCEPT_INTERVAL` parameter in `lsb.params` to 1.

What this will do is enforce a limit of 1 job per minute dispatched to any particular host, this will give the `ut` resource time to refresh and balance your workload across the hosts.